# Posting data using javascript with ODATA format

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, odata

I'm facing an issue when converting ODATA string into JSON while posting on my Dynamics CRM.
When I'm trying to serialize that way:

```
var phoneCallAssociationJsonData = '{'
               +'"@odata.id" : "https://contoso.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/phonecalls('+ phoneCallUid +')"'
               +'}';
```

And serialize it in the request like that: ***JSON.stringify(phoneCallAssociationJsonData);***

I get a BAD REQUEST response. But When I use POSTMAN to post data and I copy the following JSON:

```
{"@odata.id" : "https://contoso.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/phonecalls(12a59ec0-76b5-e611-80ed-5065f38a8ad1)"}
```

It works perfectly. 
Does someone know if there is a special way way to serialize string with odata format ?

I've tried to create a javascript object but adding a ***object.@odata.id*** is not possible because ***@*** is not an allowed character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, rather than creating a string, which you then stringify, create an OBJECT

```
var phoneCallAssociationJsonData = {
    "@odata.id" : "https://contoso.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/phonecalls("+ phoneCallUid +")"
};
```

then

```
JSON.stringify(phoneCallAssociationJsonData);
```

should now work